# Binding issue using slider in ListView in Maui

Tags: binding, maui-windows

the environment:

Visual Studio 17.4.3
Dotnet 7 v101
Mvvm Community 8.0

When I try on windows application to use a slider in a list view the slider doesn't get binded correctly to the items of the list view (at least my uneducated guess). The slider looks to be in de default state.

i have a model for changeable properties like this:

```
public class ChangeableProperty {     
    public int MinValue {get;set;}
    public int MaxValue {get;set;}
    public int Value {get;set;}     
}
[ObservableProperty]     
IEnumerable<ChangeableProperty> dynamicProperties;`
```

I get them from the backend and try to show them in the Maui App using Mvvm Toolkit.

The ListView is showing and in the first column I added some labels to show the values.

When using the slider the values are not used.

The source is

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DynamicProperties, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="imaging:ChangeableProperty">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"
                           FontAttributes="Italic"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="Min"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="3"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="{Binding StartValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                           FontAttributes="Italic"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="4"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="Max"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="5"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="{Binding EndValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                           FontAttributes="Italic"/>
                    <Slider Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.RowSpan="4"
                            x:Class="ChangeableProperty"
                            Minimum="{Binding MinValue}"
                            Maximum="{Binding MaxValue}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            Value="{Binding Value, Converter{StaticResource DoubleToIntConverter}}"
                            MinimumTrackColor="Red"
                            MaximumTrackColor="Blue"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 <ListView>
```

The slider appears to have the default settings. Is it possible to have the changed in a property notified? The demos I saw are related to showing only the list (so when entries available show them) but not for editing using a slider.

Is this a known issue or is it not possible to use a slider in a list view like this?

Kind regards

Comment: Update: Looks like it has nothing to do with the ListView. I changed
    [ObservableProperty]     
    IEnumerable<ChangeableProperty> dynamicProperties;
to
    [ObservableProperty]     
    ChangeableProperty dynamicProperties;
and the issues is the same....
Something with my binding goes wrong then (even I don't get any issues shown)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this issue can be replicated when setting binding to the Slider. The binding value of the `Slider` fails to change when using binding. This issue looks similar to an existing one in Github:[Setting Slider.Maximum or Slider.Minimum resets binding of Slider.Value](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12285). You can follow up there.

Also, you can raise a new issue on Github via this link:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose